# mapping dictionary items and normalize them

Tags: python, math, dictionary, nested-lists

How can I build a function that receives a dictionary like:-

```
dic = {'a':0.4, 'b':0.2, 'c':0.1, 'd':0.5}
```

and a list of lists:-

```
l = [['a','red',1],['c','green', 4],['b','blue', 5]]
```

So that I can map the letters of the list in the dictionary and return their values normalized, like this:

```
result = sqrt((0.4^2) + (0.1^2) + (0.2^2))
```

This is my attempt:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm
def normalizing(dic, l1):
    result = []
    for i in dic:
        if i in l1:
            result.append(dic[i])
    return norm(result)
```

returning 0.0

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to get l = [["a","a",1], ["c","green","c"]] ? What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: There is no way this code to work since 'a' is not in the array [['a', 'red', 1], ['c', 'green', 4], ['b', 'blue', 5]] it is in the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result gives 0 because of the way you are doing the for loop:

```
for i in dic: # for every letter in the dictionary
    if i in l1:  # if that letter is one of the elements of the list l1
```

i is never one of the elements of l1 in your example, but ["a", "red", 1], for example. You are comparing one letter to that list, and of course it tells you it does not find it.

Assuming that you never have more than "a list within a list", that is, assuming you don't need to iterate level after level with recursivity, a code that could work is:

```
import math
for letter in dic:
    for element in l1:
        if letter in element:
            result.append(dic[letter]**2 * element.count(letter))
return math.sqrt(sum(result))
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that the elements of the list of lists are repeated, so my question is that the condition "if letterin element will work?

Comment: No, if they can be repeated within the same element (if you can have ["a","red","a"] then see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

If for array 'l' the elements 'a', 'b','c' are unique you can use a dictionary:

```
def normalizing(dic, l1):
    result = []      
    for i in dic:
        if any(i in row for row in l1):
            result.append(dic[i]) 
    return norm(result)

    Output: 0.458257569496
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I forgot to mention that the elements are not unique for array 'l'

Answer (score 0):

```
dic =  {'a': 0.4, 'c': 0.1, 'b': 0.2, 'd': 0.5}
l = [['a', 'red', 1], ['c', 'green', 4], ['b', 'blue', 5]]

import math

def normalizing(dic, l):
    result = []
    for i in dic:
        if i in [j[0] for j in l]:
            result.append(dic[i])

    print result #[0.4, 0.1, 0.2]
    return math.sqrt(sum(k*k for k in result))
```

result :-

```
>>>normalizing(dic, l)
0.45825756949558405
```

Comment: Excelent let me chk this one to. Cheers